# OpenCV - Meanshift clustering

Tags: opencv, mean-shift

Is there a meanshift clustering implementation in OpenCV? If so, is there any documentation about how I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

As you may know, this is not the place to ask this kind of questions (here you should come with programming problems...).

Regarding your question, OpenCv only has **meanshift for tracking**. For example, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_meanshift/py_meanshift.html) you can find a tutorial for Python. The basic idea of using meanshift is the following:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)#Convert the image to HSV colorspace
dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1) #Use gthe Hue to backproject the color histogram
ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit) #Apply meanshit to get the new location of the element
```

the result `track_window` will contain the new position of the element. As simple as that. Hope it helps

Comment: i think this doesn't do clustering but tracking

Answer (score 3):

There is a [pyramid mean shift filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#pyrmeanshiftfiltering) that can be used as a building block for creating your own mean shift segmentation or a GPU based [mean shift segmentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-meanshiftsegmentation).

Comment: Function pyrMeanShiftFiltering() uses openCL now at least for pyramid building and dilation, so it is also GPU-based hence no need to use proprietary CUDA solutions.